# Can you paint water resistant MDF?

Tags: paint, mdf

Can you paint water resistant MDF (the green stuff like [this](http://www.wickes.co.uk/Wickes-Moisture-Resistance-MDF-Board-18x1220x2440mm/p/190138))? If so, what type of paint is required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the link that you supplied in the [product details](http://www.wickes.co.uk/Wickes-Moisture-Resistance-MDF-Board-18x1220x2440mm/p/190138#tab-details_content) section:

> Can be finished with varnish or either oil or water-based paints

So yes, you can paint it with water or oil based paints and varnishes.